# Using Dependency Injection on a method in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, structuremap

Created a ASP.Net MVC3 application with DI container and using StructureMap.
Everything works in controller method. But how can i do for a global.asax method?

Here I set the dependency resolver  , Application_Start of global.ascx

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
    LoadApplicationMetaData(?,?,?);
    }

      private void LoadApplicationMetaData(IMetaDataService metaService, ITenantService tenantService, ICacheStorage store)
    {
        store.Add("TenantMeta", tenantService.GetAllTenants());

    }

    public class TenantService : ITenantService
    {
    private readonly ITenantRepository TenantRepsitory;

    public TenantService(ITenantRepository _tenantRepository)
    {
        TenantRepsitory = _tenantRepository;
    }
    }
```

In the this below line how can i do loosely coupling for a method call.

```
  **LoadApplicationMetaData(?,?,?); what should be passed**
```

***Note: TenantService class is expecting ITenantRepository***

Comment: I don't know very much StructureMap, but I think you could take the instance from your container. (since you've registred)

Comment: @FelipeOriani Thanks, After reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512040/ninject-ing-a-dependency-in-global-asax i found the way to get the instance from my DI container. It is working for me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
```

You clearly have a reference to the StructureMap container (your variable `container`) so just call `container.GetInstance<IMetaDataService>()` etc.